# How can I use large hexadecimal values as training data? In machine learning,

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

I am thinking of doing machine learning using `sklearn`. But the training data I have is a large hexadecimal value. How do I process this into training data? The code below is an example of a hexadecimal value

`import sklearn` `hex_train='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`

All the training data I have are these values. I don't know how to preprocess these values and use them as training data. What I know is that should I convert these values into `float` types?

Comment: What does the value **mean**?

Comment: This is the payload value of the packet.

Comment: Yes, so what does it mean? What kind of *features* should the AI have access to? Just each bit by itself?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to convert hex to decimal !

```
import binascii


def convert_hex_to_dec(string):
    try:
        return int(string, 16)
    except ValueError:
        return int(binascii.hexlify(string.encode('utf-8')), 16)
    except TypeError:
        return int(hex(0,), 16)
```

Comment: If I change hexadecimal numbers to integers, doesn't it take too long to train because the value gets too big? The training data I have is large in capacity and large in number.